# Behavior when you set an element of a vector of classes equal to a class

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, variable-assignment

If I have a class:

```
Class aClass
{
    vector<aClass> connections;
}
```

with everything else declared properly, if I were to do:

```
aClass a = new aClass();
aClass b = new aClass();

b.connections.push_back(a);
```

would this create a reference to `a` or would it duplicate the class.

I would like it to be a pointer to the class but I wasn't sure if I needed extra syntax to ensure this. I remember reading that when a class is declared `aClass a = new aClass` it is creating a pointer to the object in the heap but I wasn't sure what would happen here.

For reference this is for something like a linked list.

Also if anyone can think of a better title for this question go ahead and edit it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `connections` should be `vector<aClass*>`, `aClass a` should be `aClass* a`.
2. Then, for `b.connections.push_back(a);`, the value of the pointer will be copied, not the pointee (i.e. the object being pointed).
3. I'll suggest you to use [smart pointers](http://en.cppreference.com/book/intro/smart_pointers) instead of raw pointers, if you do want to use pointers, like `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<aClass>>`.

Comment: Thanks, I haven't done much c++ programming for a few years so I couldn't remember exactly what would happen here.

Comment: As a question about pointers, if a program is closed and there are still pointers referencing objects, will those objects be deleted and garbage collected? or will they cause a memory leak

Comment: @Cjen1 If you use raw pointer, `new` sth but don't `delete` it, then will cause memory leak. That's why I suggested smart pointers.

Comment: @sonyuanyao Even when the program that was referencing it is closed?

Comment: @Cjen1 If the program ends the memory will be collected by OS. But the destructor of class won't be invoked and might be a potential problem. Anyway it's not a good idea in C++.

Comment: @Cjen1 Actually, it depends on how the objects being pointed at were instantiated.

Answer (score 0):

First, `vector<aClass>` is not a vector of classes, it's a vector of instances of a class.

Second, `aClass a = new aClass();` is hard to make to compile in C++. In most cases a default constructed instance of a class is created simply as `aClass a;`, and `new aClass()` usually returns *a pointer* to a fresh instance of the class.

Third, even if you `push_back` an instance to the vector, it is copied.

For default-constructed objects, you can construct a fresh object at the end of the vector by `resize`ing the vector by 1.

Since 2011, you can construct an instance via non-default constructor (with non-empty set of construction arguments) directly inside the vector using `emplace_back`.

Answer (score 0):

If the code is made to be compilable, which I think what you intended then:

The [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) says that is has 2 overloads

```
void push_back( const T& value );
void push_back( T&& value );
```

So as long as you don't explicitly `std::move` or type cast or `push_back` return value from a function then the first overload will trigger, which means that copying `push_back` will be called. Otherwise the second, moving will be called.

**EDIT:** type cast and `std::move` is the same thing under the hood. But, it preserves const correctness, thus if you were to pass `const T`, then std::move will make it `const T&&`, which is very dangerous in overload resolution.

You shouldn't pass `const T&&` ever, about why read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10770181/should-a-move-constructor-take-a-const-or-non-const-rvalue-reference).

Answer (score 0):

```
aClass a = new aClass();
aClass b = new aClass();

b.connections.push_back(a);
```

It will not even compile. As someone mentioned you should write `aClass *a` and `aClass *b`.

```
    aClass a;
    aClass b;

    b.connections.push_back(a);
```

This will copy the value to the vector, because your vector holds aClass objects (values, not addresses). It doesn't copy any address. However, if you did something like this:

```
vector<aClass*> connections;
aClass *a = new aClass();
aClass *b = new aClass();
b.connections.push_back(a);
```

Then a vector will hold a pointers to aClass objects (instances of aClass). So in this case connections[0] will point to `a` object. And if you do this::

```
 cout << connections[0]<< endl;
cout << a << endl;
```

Then these lines are equal. They will print the same thing (same address).

Finally, if you delete that `a` object:

```
delete a;
```

Then it will point to that place in memory that object was placed in, but there is no `a` object anymore. So you can not do:

```
cout << a << endl;
```

But you still can do:

```
cout << connections[0] << endl;
```

And it will print the same address as before.