# How to resolve dangling const ref

Tags: c++

The following short program

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

std::vector<int> someNums()
{
    return {3, 5, 7, 11};
}

class Woop
{
public:
    Woop(const std::vector<int>& nums) : numbers(nums) {}
    void report()
    {
        for (int i : numbers)
            std::cout << i << ' ';
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
private:
    const std::vector<int>& numbers;
};

int main()
{
    Woop woop(someNums());
    woop.report();
}
```

has a dangling reference problem, that no compiler seems to warn about.
The issue is that temporaries can be bound to const-refs, which you may
then keep around. The question then is; Is there a method of avoiding getting into this problem? Preferably one that
does not involve sacrificing const correctness, or always making
copies of big objects.

Comment: That's tricky. I can asure you that I think twice before I make a member variable const reference. If in doubt, I would consider to model this data somehow that smart pointer can be involved (either `std::unique_ptr` for exclusive ownership, or `std::shared_ptr` or shared ownership, or `std::weak_ptr` to, at least, recognize lost data).

Comment: In C++, you don't pay for what you don't need/use. It is up to the programmer to take care that the referred object's lifetime does not end while the reference is still in use/existing. Same thing for raw pointers, ... There are smart pointers to bring you the features you asked for :)

Comment: Reference members are always a mistake: https://herbsutter.com/2020/02/23/references-simply/

Comment: Though compiler does not warn, this bug is catchable by Valgrind and `-fsanitize=address`. I don't think there is any best practice to avoid it without sacrificing performance.

Comment: See also: [preventing unwanted binding to a temporary in one declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42343776/402169)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In situation when some method keeps a reference after returning it is a good idea to utilize `std::reference_wrapper` instead of normal reference:

```
#include <functional>

class Woop
{
public:
    using NumsRef = ::std::reference_wrapper<const std::vector<int>>;
    Woop(NumsRef nums) : numbers_ref{nums} {}
    void report()
    {
        for (int i : numbers_ref.get())
            std::cout << i << ' ';
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
private:
    NumsRef numbers_ref;
};
```

1. it already comes with a set of overloads preventing binding of rvalues and unintended passing of temporaries, so there is no need to bother with an extra prohibited overload taking a rvalue `Woop (std::vector<int> const &&) = delete;` for your method:

```
Woop woop{someNums()}; // error
woop.report();
```

2. it allows implicit binding of lvalues so it won't break existing valid invocations:

```
auto nums{someNums()};
Woop woop{nums}; // ok
woop.report();
```

3. it allows explicit binding of lvalues which is a good practice to indicate that caller will keep the reference after returning:

```
auto nums{someNums()};
Woop woop{::std::ref(nums)}; // even better because explicit
woop.report();
```

Answer (score 12):

One way to make your class less vulnerable could be to add a deleted constructor that takes a right-ref. This would stop your class instance from making bindings to temporaries.

```
Woop(std::vector<int>&& nums)  =delete;
```

This deleted constructor would actually make the O/P code not compile, which may be the behaviour you are looking for?

Answer (score 3):

I agree with the other answers and comments that you should think carefully if you really need to store a reference inside the class. And that if you do, you'll probably want a non-const pointer to a const vector instead (i.e. `std::vector<int> const * numbers_`).

However, if that's the case, I find that the other currently posted answers are beside the point. They're all showing you how to make `Woop` own those values.

If you can assure that the vector you pass in will outlive your `Woop` instance, then you can explicitly disable constructing a `Woop` from an rvalue. That's possible using this C++11 syntax:

```
Woop (std::vector<int> const &&) = delete;
```

Now your example code won't compile anymore. The compiler with give an error similar to:

```
prog.cc: In function 'int main()':
prog.cc:29:25: error: use of deleted function 'Woop::Woop(const std::vector<int>&&)'
   29 |     Woop woop(someNums());
      |                         ^
prog.cc:15:5: note: declared here
   15 |     Woop(std::vector<int> const &&) = delete;
      |     ^~~~
```

P.S.: You probably want an explicit constructor, see e.g. [What does the explicit keyword mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121162/what-does-the-explicit-keyword-mean).

Comment: I seem to have stolen your answer there. Sorry!

Answer (score 1):

To prevent that particular case, you can choose to either take a pointer (since `Weep(&std::vector<int>{1,2,3})` isn't allowed) or you could take a non-const reference which will also error on a temporary.

```
Woop(const std::vector<int> *nums);
Woop(std::vector<int> *nums);
Woop(std::vector<int>& nums);
```

These still don't guarantee the value remains valid, but stops the easiest mistake at least, doesn't create a copy, and doesn't need `nums` be created in a special way (e.g. as `std::shared_ptr` or `std::weak_ptr` does).

`std::scoped_lock` taking a reference to the mutex would be an example, and one where unique/shared/weak ptr is not really wanted. Often the `std::mutex` will just be a basic member or local variable. You still have to be very careful, but in these cases it is generally easy to determine the life span.

`std::weak_ptr` is another option for non-owning, but then you force the caller to use `shared_ptr` (and thus also heap allocate), and sometimes that isn't wanted.

If a copy is OK, that just avoids the issue.

If `Woop` should take ownership either pass as an r-value and move (and avoid pointer/reference issues entirely), or use `unique_ptr` if you can't move the value itself or want the pointer to remain valid.

```
// the caller can't continue to use nums, they could however get `numbers` from Woop or such like
// or just let Woop only manipulate numbers directly.
Woop(std::vector<int> &&nums) 
   : numbers(std::move(nums)) {}
std::vector<int> numbers;

// while the caller looses the unique_ptr, they might still use a raw pointer, but be careful.
// Or again access numbers only via Woop as with the move construct above.
Woop(std::unique_ptr<std::vector<int>> &&nums) 
    : numbers(std::move(nums)) {}
std::unique_ptr<std::vector<int>> numbers;
```

Or if ownership is shared, you can use `shared_ptr` for everything, and it will be deleted along with the final reference, but this can make keeping track of object life cycles get very confusing if over-used.

Answer (score 1):

You may use `template programming` and `arrays` if you want to have an object that holds a `const` container. Due to the `constexpr` constructor and `constexpr arrays` you achieve `const correctness` and `compile time execution`.

Here is a post that may be interesting: [std::move a const vector](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52579572/7091177)

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>


std::array<int,4>  someNums()
{
    return {3, 5, 7, 11};
}


template<typename U, std::size_t size>
class Woop
{
public:

template<typename ...T>
    constexpr Woop(T&&... nums) : numbers{nums...} {};

    template<typename T, std::size_t arr_size>
    constexpr Woop(std::array<T, arr_size>&& arr_nums) : numbers(arr_nums) {};

    void report()
    const {
        for (auto&& i : numbers)
            std::cout << i << ' ';
         std::cout << '\n';
    }



private: 
    const std::array<U, size> numbers;
    //constexpr vector with C++20
};

int main()
{
    Woop<int, 4> wooping1(someNums());
    Woop<int, 7> wooping2{1, 2, 3, 5, 12 ,3 ,51};

    wooping1.report();
    wooping2.report();
    return 0;
}
```

[run code](https://onlinegdb.com/rJYAAWSH8)

Output:

```
3 5 7 11                                                                                                                        
1 2 3 5 12 3 51
```

Comment: With the numbers as an `std::array` this is guaranteed to copy, even if a move would otherwise be available. On top of that `wooping1` and `wooping2` are not the same type, which is less than ideal.

Comment: @sp2danny thanks for you feedback and I have to agree with you on both points. user7860670 provided a better solution :)