# what does std::move(const shared_ptr reference) mean?

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, move-semantics, stdmove

The following is toy code I am trying... I understand the first and second one. The first one give the ownership to `_p`. The second one copies `p` to `_p`.
but I don't understand the third one...

What does `std::move` of `const shared_ptr &` mean? Thank you.

```cpp
class P { };

class A {
public:
    // first one
    A(std::shared_ptr<P> &p, int) : _p(std::move(p))
    {
        std::cout << "1st Ctor: "
                  << p.use_count() << ", " << _p.use_count() << std::endl;
    }

    // second one
    A(const std::shared_ptr<P> &p, std::string) : _p(p)
    {
        std::cout << "2nd Ctor: "
                  << p.use_count() << ", " << _p.use_count() << std::endl;
    }

    // third one
    A(const std::shared_ptr<P> &p) : _p(std::move(p))
    {
        std::cout << "3rd Ctor: "
                  << p.use_count() << ", " << _p.use_count() << std::endl;
    }

private:
    std::shared_ptr<P> _p;
};

int main()
{
    {
        std::shared_ptr<P> p = std::make_shared<P>();
        A a(p, 1);
        std::cout << "1. body: " << p.use_count() << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "-------------" << std::endl;
    {
        std::shared_ptr<P> p = std::make_shared<P>();
        A a(p, "2");
        std::cout << "2. body: " << p.use_count() << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "-------------" << std::endl;
    {
        std::shared_ptr<P> p = std::make_shared<P>();
        A a(p);
        std::cout << "3. body: " << p.use_count() << std::endl;
    }
 }
```

Result is:

```
$ ./a.out 
1st Ctor: 0, 1
1. body: 0
-------------
2nd Ctor: 2, 2
2. body: 2
-------------
3rd Ctor: 2, 2
3. body: 2
```

(updated: adding comment to clarify which one is first one, second one, etc.)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10770181/should-a-move-constructor-take-a-const-or-non-const-rvalue-reference

Comment: You probably should be more clear on what you mean by "the first one" (the first line, the first block, the first call to `std::move`?). The same applies to your question: what do you mean by "`std::move` **of** `const shared_ptr &`"? Cite specific lines.

Comment: On my team, 1st, 2nd and 3rd would all be dinged as bad practice in a code review.  For transferring ownership `A(std::shared_ptr<P>&& p)` (which is a wee bit odd for a shared_ptr), or `A(std::shared_ptr<P> p)` (typical pattern for any sink parameter) would be the way to express the intent.

Comment: @Eljay, Thanks for the comment. what you suggested is clearer to use. With your comment, I found that `const shared_ptr &` seems somewhat ambiguous in terms of copy/move.

Comment: @eric `const shared_ptr &` is unambiguously not for moving.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`std::move` is a function which converts the argument to an rvalue reference. The function call is an xvalue expression.

When the argument is a reference to const, then the result of the conversion is an rvalue to const. If you initialise from rvalue to const, copy constructor will be used because the rvalue reference parameter to **non-const** of the move constructor cannot bind to rvalue reference argument to const.

> I think there is also an implicit question by OP of how `_p(std::move(p))` might differ from `_p(p)`

`_p(std::move(p))` doesn't differ from `_p(p)` in case of `const std::shared_ptr<T>`.

In theory, if `decltype(_p)` was a type that had a constructor `T(const T&&)`, then there would be a difference, since that constructor would be invoked by `_p(std::move(p))` but not by `_p(p)`. Such constructor would be quite unconventional, but technically well-formed. `std::shared_ptr` doesn't have such constructor.

Comment: I think there is also an implicit question by OP of how `_p(std::move(p))` might differ from `_p(p)`

Comment: @M.M I had considered that there was no need to mention that `_p(p)` also does a copy. I've added clarification.

Comment: OK. I guess it would differ for a class that had separate `const T&&`  and `T&&` constructors

Comment: @M.M Indeed it would. Have you seen `const T&&` constructor used by the way? I've seen it a few times with non-constructor functions, but never in a constructor.

Answer (score 5):

[`std::move`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move) just performs conversion and produces xvalue (rvalue).

When being passed a `const std::shared_ptr<P>`, its return type would be `const std::shared_ptr<P>&&`. Then for `_p(std::move(p))` the [copy constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) of `std::shared_ptr` (but not [move constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) which taking rvalue-reference to **non-const**) will be called, the effect is just same as the 2nd case.

Basically move operation tends to perform modification on the object being moved; it's not supposed to work on `const` objects.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I tried to inherit `std::shared_ptr` and printed at copy ctor and move ctor. As you answered, when the param was `const shared_ptr &`, copy ctor was called!!