# Returning const reference parameter without copying

Tags: c++, move-semantics

I want to return a heavy object which I pass as a `const` reference without copying. The code looks something like this:

```
#include <iostream>

class heavy_obj {
    public:
        heavy_obj() {
            std::cout << "Standard" << std::endl;
        }

        heavy_obj(const heavy_obj&) {
            std::cout << "Copy" << std::endl;
        }

        heavy_obj(heavy_obj&& t) {
            std::cout << "Move" << std::endl;
        }

};

heavy_obj return_obj_or_default(const heavy_obj& t, bool ret) {
    if(ret) {
        return std::move(t); // Copy gets called here
    } else {
        return heavy_obj();
    }
}

int main()
{
    heavy_obj t {/* Something */};
    heavy_obj t2 = return_obj_or_default(t, true);
    heavy_obj t3 = return_obj_or_default(heavy_obj(/* Something Else */), true);
    /* Output:
       Standard
       Copy
       Standard
       Copy
    */
    return 0;
}
```

However, if I declare the move constructor as non-`const` as shown above the copy constructor will be called, which I do not want. I could remove the `const` in the function `heavy_obj return_test(heavy_obj& t, bool ret)` but then I am no longer able to pass rvalues as parameters.

How do I achieve my desired behavior? Marking the parameter to the move constructor as `const`: `heavy_obj(const heavy_obj&& t)`? Though it contradicts [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10770181/should-a-move-constructor-take-a-const-or-non-const-rvalue-reference)?

Comment: **then I am no longer able to pass rvalues as parameters** **Marking the parameter to the move constructor** ,why don't you use **return_obj_or_default(heavy_obj&& t,bool ret)**

Comment: @HongluWong Because I want to pass either a reference as `return_obj_or_default(t, true)` or a rvalue `return_obj_or_default(heavy_obj(), true)`, I could not pass a reference with `heavy_obj&& t`

Comment: you should use **std::forward**,code like this ` template<typename T> typename std::decay<T>::type return_obj_or_default(T&& t,bool ret){  if( ret ) return std::forward<T>(t); return  typename std::decay<T>::type{};`

Comment: Hmm, a lot of hacking for such a basic task, but at least it works with `move`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't move from a `const` value, so the function can't take by `const &`.

You could do this, so the caller has to supply an rvalue, either moving or explicitly copying lvalues they wish to pass.

```
heavy_obj return_obj_or_default(heavy_obj&& t, bool ret) {
    if(ret) {
        return std::move(t);
    } else {
        return heavy_obj();
    }
}
```

Or you could do this, so the caller doesn't have to do anything special, but it will implicitly copy lvalues.

```
heavy_obj return_obj_or_default(heavy_obj t, bool ret) {
    if(ret) {
        return std::move(t);
    } else {
        return heavy_obj();
    }
}
```